# Banco de Dados em Android

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, web-service, modelagem

Olá! Há poucos dias, em uma pergunta que fiz aqui no StackOverflow, eu disse que estava começando a desenvolver para a plataforma Android. Esta semana foi bastante produtiva e eu já estou com algumas ideias para aplicar, mas tenho uma série de dúvidas. Gostaria que vocês me respondessem.

Eu pensei em um projeto que poderia ser usado tanto no computador quanto em dispositivos móveis. Para isto terei que utilizar webservices, correto? Poderiam me recomendar alguma abordagem adequada para atingir este objetivo?

Isto está relacionado a um outro fator, que é sobre armazenamento de dados. Nos meus estudos, durante esta semana, eu criei algumas coisas utilizando o SQlite. Para um projeto maior eu posso usar outro banco?

A modelagem dos dados também é feita da forma que usualmente se vê em desenvolvimento de sistemas para desktop?

Eu sei que já são três perguntas, e que podem parecer conceituais. Mas é que eu estou meio perdido e não consegui encontrar nada muito relevante nos cursos que realizei nos últimos dias.

Então. Quais são as considerações de vocês?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se por "abordagem adequada para atingir este objetivo" você quer dizer qual tecnologia utilizar para fazer seus webservices, escolha a que preferir. Se tem mais facilidade com Java, use Java, caso contrário é comum usar PHP.

O banco que você vai usar no dispositivo é uma coisa (e costuma estar disponível somente o SQLite mesmo). Ele não tem nada a ver com o banco que você vai ter no servidor e que seus webservices vão acessar. No servidor costuma-se usar MySQL, PostgreSQL, entre outros. Note que no servidor os bancos de dados geralmente suportam concorrência (não há conflitos quando são feitas múltiplas requisições a esses bancos), já no SQLite do dispositivo essa concorrência não é suportada e você precisa implementar manualmente (isso caso exista a chance de mais de um thread do seu aplicativo tente acessar os dados do dispositivo concorrentemente, caso contrário não precisa se preocupar com isso).

A recomendação é: não acesse o banco do servidor diretamente a partir do dispositivo, faça isso por meio de web services.

Sim, a modelagem dos dados também é feita da forma que usualmente se vê em desenvolvimento para desktop.

Comment: Bastante esclarecedor, @Piovezan. Eu não imaginava que teria que usar um banco na aplicação do Android e outra no servidor. Eu pensava que eu faria as requisições direto no servidor e que web services serviriam para isso. Ou seja: eu imaginava que um web service faria sentido só em casos em que há mais de uma aplicação consumindo os mesmos dados.

Outra dúvida surgiu: se eu vou utilizar o SQlite no celular e um outro bd no servidor, o web service seria para manter a sincronia destes dados?

Abração, e obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Só para ter certeza que você entendeu: quando você faz um aplicativo móvel geralmente vai ter mais de um aplicativo acessando os mesmos dados mesmo. Um webservice pode ser chamado por vários aplicativos e cada chamada vai acessar o mesmo banco. O problema de se chamar diretamente o banco (via JDBC no caso do Android, sem passar por um webservice) vem do fato de não se ter uma rede estável ao longo da qual a conexão com o banco será mantida sem risco de uma eventual queda.

Comment: Quanto à sua última pergunta, não necessariamente. Vai depender de cada tipo de aplicativo. Muitas vezes você vai querer guardar dados localmente que não são "espelhos" dos dados do servidor, como por exemplo logins/senhas, configurações do usuário, etc.

Comment: Não esquecendo que para o caso de dados mais simples (um inteiro ou uma string, por exemplo) o Android dispõe do recurso de Shared Preferences.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, @Piovezan. Acho que suas respostas já estabelecem um ponto de partida para alguns estudos. Valeu mesmo!!!

Answer (score -1):

Você esta indo pelo caminho certo.

Qualquer tipo de acesso a "banco de dados externo" (vamos chamar assim), deve ser feito via WebServices. Da uma olhada nesse artigo http://www.androidpro.com.br/usando-banco-de-dados-externo-no-android/.

Para armazenamento interno no Android (banco de dados) você tem o SQLite para fazer isso. Porém tome cuidado, é um banco muito limitado e simples, use com moderação para sua aplicação não fica muito pesada e lenta.

Obs: Não guarde imagens e/ou arquivos no SQLite, isso faz a performance cair muito.

Sobre a modelagem dos dados, é relativamente igual. Você precisa definir tanto no seu servidor onde fica seu WebService quanto na sua aplicação a modelagem dos dados do seu aplicativo.
Só no SQLite tome cuidado com modelagens e relacionamento muito complexos.

Abs.